# Integrating the Planck Function over certain filter ranges

Tags: numerical-integration, physics, astronomy

[image: This should be straightforward, but I'm getting errors here]ClearAll["Global`*"]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

h = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity["PlanckConstant"], "SIBase"]];
c = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity["SpeedOfLight"], "SIBase"]];
k = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity["BoltzmannConstant"], "SIBase"]];

(*B and V filters*)
Bmin = (440 - 50)*10^-9;
Bmax = (440 + 50)*10^-9;
Vmin = (550 - 50)*10^-9;
Vmax = (50 + 50)*10^-9;

B[λ_, T_] := (2 h c^2)/λ^5 1/(E^((h c)/(λ k T)) - 1)
fb[T_] = NIntegrate[B[λ, T], {λ, Bmin, Bmax}]
fv[T_] = NIntegrate[B[λ, T], {λ, Vmin, Vmax}]

(*NIntegrate produces errors here*)

bvu = -2.5 Log10[fb[T]/fv[T]]

bv[T_] = bvu[T] - bvu[10^4]

FindRoot[bv[t] == 0.8, {t, 5000}]
```

Comment: You define `fb` with `=` (called `Set`). When doing that the right hand side is evaluated as part of the assignment. If you use `:=` (called `SetDelayed`), the right hand side is evaluated only when the function is called (hopefully with a numerical value passed for `T`). You should write `fb[T_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[...]`

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

h = QuantityMagnitude[
   UnitConvert[Quantity["PlanckConstant"], "SIBase"]];
c = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[Quantity["SpeedOfLight"], "SIBase"]];
k = QuantityMagnitude[
   UnitConvert[Quantity["BoltzmannConstant"], "SIBase"]];

(*B and V filters*)
Bmin = (440 - 50)*10^-9;
Bmax = (440 + 50)*10^-9;
Vmin = (550 - 50)*10^-9;
Vmax = (50 + 50)*10^-9;



B[λ_, T_] := (2 h c^2)/λ^5 1/(E^((h c)/(λ k T)) - 1)
fb[T_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[B[λ, T], {λ, Bmin, Bmax}]
fv[T_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[B[λ, T], {λ, Vmin, Vmax}]
bvu[T_] := -2.5 Log10[fb[T]/fv[T]]
bv[T_] := bvu[T] - bvu[10^4]


Plot[bv[t] - 0.8, {t, 0, 16000}] // Quiet
```

[image]

```
 FindRoot[bv[t] == 0.8, {t, 15000}] // Quiet
```

> {t -> 15321.8 - 1.35*10^-11 I}

```
FindRoot[bv[t] == 0.8, {t, 100}] // Quiet
```

> {t -> 269.09 + 1.58244*10^-13 I}